# How to get the token of the user in TFS through an API Call when creating tickets from Slack

Tags: node.js, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Microsoft bot-framework for Nodejs that is hooked with slack. My bot basically listens for commands, for example,

Me: @bot create a bug
bot: Created a bug

David:  @bot create a bug
bot: Created a bug

The problem is, I have my token hardcoded inside the program. So, David is basically creating a ticket as me. Is there anyway to get the token of the user who sends the command and create a ticket as that specific user? 
Thanks

Comment: There's a VSTS-Bot example written in c# here: https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/VSTS-Bot  Basically, you need to have the user's sign into TFS (using a signin card, or something within the bot) so your bot has the token for the correct user.

Comment: Did you use VSTS or on-premise TFS?